# How to read numpy array without truncation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, truncation

I was surprised I couldn't find this more easily. How do we set the number of digits to truncate to when reading in a numpy array?

```
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
pose_raw =  [0.8646331429481506, -0.22936344146728516, -0.4469817578792572, 0.0, 0.3616204857826233, 0.9017571806907654, 0.2367781400680542, 0.0, 0.3487676680088043, -0.3663671910762787, 0.8626390695571899, 0.0, -0.534120500087738, -2.0878100395202637, -0.4539491534233093, 1.0]

pose = np.array(pose_raw).reshape((4,4)).T
print("raw ", p["pose"])
print("processed ", pose)
```

Gives the following

> raw  [0.8646331429481506, -0.22936344146728516, -0.4469817578792572, 0.0, 0.3616204857826233, 0.9017571806907654, 0.2367781400680542, 0.0, 0.3487676680088043, -0.3663671910762787, 0.8626390695571899, 0.0, -0.534120500087738, -2.0878100395202637, -0.4539491534233093, 1.0]
> Blockquote
>
> processed  [[ 0.86463314  0.36162049  0.34876767 -0.5341205 ]
> [-0.22936344  0.90175718 -0.36636719 -2.08781004]  [-0.44698176
> 0.23677814  0.86263907 -0.45394915]  [ 0.          0.          0.          1.        ]]

Comment: In other words, `threshold` doesn't seem to be the correct option - you're looking for `precision`. Try `np.set_printoptions(precision=16)`.

Comment: Are you sure it's truncated or it's just that `print` only gets you so many digits.

Comment: You're totally right about the threshold/precision thing. When I later passed the numpy array to something else it was using numpy's string representation and was therefore truncated.